# Buttons behind my view? iOS

Tags: ios, xcode

I have the following (buttons not show up when running the app somehow-they are behind my view, which is a Google Maps view by the way):

[image]

If I click on either buttons, go to Editor/Arrange there is no possibility of sending/arranging the buttons forward, only backward. Why is this happening? How can I make my buttons visible?

Comment: You have added the buttons inside the mapView as subviews. Move them outside of it, simply drag them out of the MapView and add them below it on the left column tree.

Comment: I did. Same problem persists

Comment: When you move them out, make sure they are BELOW the MapView in the left column. The ones below are the ones on TOP.

Comment: I will add the answer you can accept if you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have added the `UIButtons` inside the `mapView` as subviews. Move them outside of it, simply drag them out of the `MapView` and add them below it on the left column tree.

When you move them out, make sure they are **BELOW** the `MapView` in the left column.

The ones below on the left tree are the ones that end up on TOP.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this function

```
[self.myButton.superview bringSubviewToFront:self.myButton];
```

this will make myButton on top of all it's superview's views

apply it in the way you need it

Answer (score 0):

You have to put your `UIButtons` out side the `Map view`,
Something like this:

[image]